# cannot get elasticsearch service to run in ubuntu 17?

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch

I am following the steps here to install and get elasticsearch to work.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-elasticsearch-on-ubuntu-16-04

I have a ubuntu 17 and i am logged in as non root user with sudo rights.

I did the following steps

```
sudo apt-get update

wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-6.1.1.deb

sudo dpkg -i elasticsearch-6.1.1.deb

sudo systemctl enable elasticsearch.service

sudo systemctl start elasticsearch
```

Finally when i test using

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200'
```

I get the following error

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused
```

Also when i do

```
service --status-all
```

i donot see elasticsearch service listed in the services list.

Please note that i have ufw installed and i have the following ports open

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

could this be preventing the 9200 port but that doesnt seem likely since internal communications should be allowed.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the output i am getting with **sudo journalctl -f**

```
-- Logs begin at Fri 2017-12-29 10:27:23 +0545. --
Dec 30 13:31:40  elasticsearch[29595]: #
Dec 30 13:31:40  elasticsearch[29595]: # There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
Dec 30 13:31:40  elasticsearch[29595]: # Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 986513408 bytes for committing reserved memory.
Dec 30 13:31:40  elasticsearch[29595]: # An error report file with more information is saved as:
```

I checked the free memory using **free -m** command

[image]

Comment: You're downloading 6.1.1 but installing 2.3.1?

Comment: sorry that was just a typo. i have corrected the command i used.

Comment: What do you see in `/var/log/elasticsearch`?

Comment: i just checked and that folder is empty.

Comment: i also disabled ufw and still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you [enable journalctl](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/deb.html#deb-running-systemd) so we can get some insights?

Comment: thanks a lot. seems like we are closing in on the solution. i have pasted above the output from sudo journalctl -f

Comment: is the lack of memory causing the error. I am using 1gb VPS.

Comment: By default ES starts with 1GB of heap (tunable in `config/jvm.options`). So either you decrease that (which is not advised) or you bump your VPS RAM.

Comment: thanks Val. that solved it. plz put your answer so that i can accept it. i changed the heapsize to 500m and it worked!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should [enable `journalctl`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/deb.html#deb-running-systemd) so we can gain some insights about what is going on.

Since it seems to be a memory issue (you have 1GB on your VPS and ES is pre-configured with 1GB heap), you have two options:

1. decrease the heap in `config/jvm.options`
2. or increase your VPS RAM

Comment: thanks val! the problem was that the ram of my vps was lower than the minimum requirement. i changed the min and max heap size to 500m from 1gb in config/jvm.options and now it ran fine.

Comment: it didn't just help. it saved the day! i cannot thank enough.