# Elasticsearch is not starting as a service

Tags: elasticsearch, service

I'm trying to start elasticsearch as a service using `sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch start` command.

When I check the status of this service using `service elasticsearch status` command I'm getting `elasticsearch dead but subsys locked` message.

From some stackoverflow questions and other blogs I tried deleting the `/var/lock/subsys/elasticsearch` file and restarting the service, checking the permission to `path.data` directory for `elasticsearch` user. But none of these solutions worked for me.

**UPDATE**

I found the log files and got the error. Elasticsearch is not starting when I added `network.host: 0.0.0.0` setting in my `elasticsearch.yml` file in order to allow requests from other servers. In that case it is failing with following error.

```
[1]: max file descriptors [64000] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65536]
[2]: max number of threads [1024] for user [elasticsearch] is too low, increase to at least [4096]
[3]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
```

Now I'm stuck here. Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: can you check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48031762/cannot-get-elasticsearch-service-to-run-in-ubuntu-17/48032157#48032157) and update your question with relevant info you can get from `journalctl` ?

Comment: Documented: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/file-descriptors.html

Comment: Thank you so much, @aholbreich. It solved the issue.