# Elasticsearch 5.6.5 cannot starup on Ubuntu14.04

Tags: elasticsearch, ubuntu-14.04

All

I am new to elasticsearch. and I have installed the elasticsearch 5.6 on Ubuntu 14.04, with apt-get following the instruction on this [page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/deb.html).

However, it fail to start when I was trying this command

> sudo -i service elasticsearch start

Then I add a log line to check what the command really is.

> log_daemon_msg "sudo -u $ES_USER $DAEMON $DAEMON_OPTS"
>
> start-stop-daemon -d $ES_HOME --start --user "$ES_USER" -c "$ES_USER" --pidfile "$PID_FILE" --exec       $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS

It returns

> sudo -u elasticsearch /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -d -p /var/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.pid -Edefault.path.logs=/var/log/elasticsearch -Edefault.path.data=/var/lib/elasticsearch -Edefault.path.conf=/etc/elasticsearch

I try to run is command directly, and the command exit without print any log. I also check the /var/log/elasticsearch, which is an empty dir.
Could anyone help to find out what do I miss?
Thanks.

BTW. I am running a 512M RAM, and 1G swap machine. and I have modifed the jvm.options to **-Xms256m** and **-Xmx256m**

Comment: Can you follow the steps here and provide some feedback? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48031762/cannot-get-elasticsearch-service-to-run-in-ubuntu-17/48032157#48032157

Comment: Hi, Val. My ubuntu 14.04 do not have a journalctl, Is there any other ways to capture the log?

Comment: It's very likely that you don't have enough RAM, 256MB sounds like way too low for ES