# How to restart my elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I installed it yesterday on my desktop(Ubuntu 16.04)

```
elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since уто 2018-04-17 10:18:51 CEST; 2min 58s ago
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co
 Main PID: 20185 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

апр 17 10:18:44 jh-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: Started Elasticsearch.
апр 17 10:18:51 jh-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
апр 17 10:18:51 jh-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Unit entered failed state.
апр 17 10:18:51 jh-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I have tried both

```
sudo update-rc.d elasticsearch defaults 95 10
sudo systemctl start elasticsearch
```

I have changed network.host and port in elasticsearch.yml

```
network.host: 192.168.0.1
http.port: 9200
```

I have done what Val suggested

```
sudo /bin/systemctl daemon-reload
sudo /bin/systemctl enable elasticsearch.service
```

If I go for

```
sudo journalctl -f
```

then I have

```
kibana[16891]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-04-17T08:37:39Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":16891,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://localhost:9200/"}
kibana[16891]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-04-17T08:37:39Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":16891,"message":"No living connections"}
```

I have tried to restart again

```
elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
 elasticsearch.service: Unit entered failed state.
 elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 milenko : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/milenko ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -f
```

What does this output mean?

I do not understant what is wrong,I have the same problem.

Comment: Can you check this and tell us what you find in the journal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48031762/cannot-get-elasticsearch-service-to-run-in-ubuntu-17/48032157#48032157 ?

Comment: @Val can you take a look now?