# Elasticsearch won't start

Tags: elasticsearch

i've just installed Elasticsearch 5.6 on SLES 12 SP3 and it won't start. I've previously installed it on Ubuntu server and it works fine, but i have to use SLES.

`systemctl status elasticsearch` return this:

```
● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fr 2018-10-05 10:37:10 CEST; 2min 29s ago
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co
  Process: 1531 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -p ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --quiet -Edefault.path.logs=${LOG_DIR} -Edefault.path.data=${DATA_DIR} -Edefault.path.conf=${CONF_DIR} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 1516 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-systemd-pre-exec (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1531 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

I've already tried set `network.host` in `/Applications/elasticsearch-2.1.1/config/elasticsearch.yml` to `0.0.0.0`, but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

`journalctl` shows this:

```
Okt 05 11:03:34 linux-m1db systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
Okt 05 11:03:34 linux-m1db systemd[1]: Started Elasticsearch.
Okt 05 11:03:34 linux-m1db elasticsearch[2317]: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x0000000085330000, 2060255232, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memo
Okt 05 11:03:34 linux-m1db elasticsearch[2317]: #
Okt 05 11:03:34 linux-m1db elasticsearch[2317]: # There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
Okt 05 11:03:34 linux-m1db elasticsearch[2317]: # Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 2060255232 bytes for committing reserved memory.
Okt 05 11:03:34 linux-m1db elasticsearch[2317]: # An error report file with more information is saved as:
Okt 05 11:03:34 linux-m1db elasticsearch[2317]: # /tmp/hs_err_pid2317.log
Okt 05 11:03:34 linux-m1db systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Okt 05 11:03:34 linux-m1db systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Unit entered failed state.
Okt 05 11:03:34 linux-m1db systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

It seems to be an Java problem.

Comment: Can you [enable `journalctl`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/deb.html#deb-running-systemd) so we can gain some insights into what's going on? (i.e. remove `--quiet` in `elasticsearch.service`)

Comment: @Val i've added it to the question.

Comment: Then you might want to check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48031762/cannot-get-elasticsearch-service-to-run-in-ubuntu-17/48032157#48032157 (hint: insufficient memory)