# Elasticsearch won't start and no logs

Tags: elasticsearch

I've been trying to start ES for hours and I can't seem to be able to do so.

The command `sudo service elasticsearch status` prints out :

```
elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since ven. 2019-01-11 12:22:33 CET; 5min ago
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co
  Process: 16713 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -Des.pidfile=$PID_DIR/elasticsearch.pid -Des.default.path.home=$ES_HOME -Des.default.path.logs=$LOG_DIR -Des.default.path.data=$DATA_DIR -Des.default.confi Main PID: 16713 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

janv. 11 12:22:33 glamuse systemd[1]: Started Elasticsearch.
janv. 11 12:22:33 glamuse systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
janv. 11 12:22:33 glamuse systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Unit entered failed state.
janv. 11 12:22:33 glamuse systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I've increased the memory and done all the fixes I could find on the internet, but I can't seem to figure out what's going on, there's not even a single log generated today... So I don't even have any trace of where the error could be.

I'm using ES version 1.7.2 (yes, it's old, but that shouldn't be a problem as it does work, and no I can't upgrade because my Elastica uses this version, anyways ...)

I'm using a vagrant machine, so it's a unix based system.

My config is as follow (removed all the useless comments) :

```
index.number_of_shards: 10
index.number_of_replicas: 1

bootstrap.mlockall: true

network.bind_host: 0
network.host: 0.0.0.0

indices.recovery.max_bytes_per_sec: 200mb
indices.store.throttle.max_bytes_per_sec : 200mb

script.engine.groovy.inline.search: on
script.engine.groovy.inline.aggs: on
script.engine.groovy.inline.update: on

index.query.bool.max_clause_count: 100000
```

I also have this conf :

```
ES_HEAP_SIZE=4g
MAX_OPEN_FILES=65535
MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY=unlimited
START_DAEMON=true
ES_USER=elasticsearch
ES_GROUP=elasticsearch
LOG_DIR=/var/log/elasticsearch
DATA_DIR=/var/lib/elasticsearch
WORK_DIR=/tmp/elasticsearch
CONF_DIR=/etc/elasticsearch
CONF_FILE=/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
RESTART_ON_UPGRADE=true
```

Any idea how can I debug this?

Comment: Waves at the great @Val for help ! :)

Comment: Can you try to enable journalctl so we can see the service logs? See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48031762/cannot-get-elasticsearch-service-to-run-in-ubuntu-17/48032157#48032157