# Elasticsearch fails on startup

Tags: elasticsearch, xenforo

I'm trying to start elasticsearch on Centos 7 and after trying to start it I type service elasticsearch status and get the following output:

```
* elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-02-14 07:50:13 EST; 5s ago
Docs: http://www.elastic.co
Process: 14472 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -p ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --quiet -Edefault.path.logs=${LOG_DIR} -Edefault.path.data=${DATA_DIR} -Edefault.path.conf=${CONF_DIR} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 14471 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-systemd-pre-exec (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 14472 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Does anyone have any idea about what is going wrong here and how I might fix it?

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48032157/4604579 (hint: check what `journalctl` spits out)

Comment: `Feb 14 09:06:08 host.server.com systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
Feb 14 09:06:08 host.server.com systemd[1]: Started Elasticsearch.
Feb 14 09:06:16 host.server.com systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 14 09:06:16 host.server.com systemd[1]: Unit elasticsearch.service entered failed state.
Feb 14 09:06:16 host.server.com systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service failed.`

Comment: Have you followed the steps [explained here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/deb.html#deb-running-systemd)?

Comment: Hi Val, yes I have.

Comment: `${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --quiet -Edefault.path.logs=${LOG_DIR} -Edefault.path.data=${DATA_DIR} -Edefault.path.conf=${CONF_DIR} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)'`

That seems to be where the problem lies but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: I meant this part `the --quiet option must be removed from the ExecStart command line in the elasticsearch.service file.`

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it didn't work. 

`Process: 13354 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -p ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid -Edefault.path.logs=${LOG_DIR} -Edefault.path.data=${DATA_DIR} -Edefault.path.conf=${CONF_DIR} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)`