# Elasticsearch won't start in ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Tags: elasticsearch

So i tried to start elasticsearch with this command:

```
systemctl start elasticsearch.service
```

and i got this error :

```
Job for elasticsearch.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered to the control process.
See "systemctl status elasticsearch.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

this is "journalctl -xe" output :

```
mai 10 10:18:49 ouss kernel: oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/system.slice/elasticsearch.service,task=java,pid=24534,uid=122
mai 10 10:18:49 ouss kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 24534 (java) total-vm:1564676kB, anon-rss:550924kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
mai 10 10:18:49 ouss kernel: oom_reaper: reaped process 24534 (java), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
mai 10 10:18:40 ouss systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
mai 10 10:18:49 ouss /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1336]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce: offset negative (-1094ms)
mai 10 10:18:49 ouss /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1336]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce short: offset negative (-1249ms)
mai 10 10:18:49 ouss /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1336]: (II) event6  - VirtualBox mouse integration: SYN_DROPPED event - some input events have been lost.
mai 10 10:18:40 ouss systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
mai 10 10:18:40 ouss systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
-- Subject: Unit elasticsearch.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit elasticsearch.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
```

My java version :

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_252"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_252-8u252-b09-1~18.04-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.252-b09, mixed mode)
```

Comment: see elasticsearch logs. Have you changed something in the configuration?

Comment: In the output you show, the important bit is `Out of memory`, so you need to increase the heap. This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48031762/cannot-get-elasticsearch-service-to-run-in-ubuntu-17/48032157#48032157

Comment: @Val so i changed in my jvm.options the values from 1g to 2g  and the problem persists:
# Xms represents the initial size of total heap space
# Xmx represents the maximum size of total heap space

-Xms2g
-Xmx2g

Comment: it seems like whatever the value of Xmx and Xms are , the service won't start

Comment: @Val i'm actually running this on a ubuntu virtual machine with 2178m of ram , maybe i should increase that ?

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja the error has actually changed after i set the java environment variable , new error:
imgur.com/a/zwpVp9l
had to screen it because its too long

Comment: @Oelmounkad, checked ur image but it doesn't contain any error log, can you try the docker or tarball installation?

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja ok i am gonna uninstall ES and do the tar installation

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja i installed it and this error occurs after starting : elasticsearch.service: Failed at step CHDIR spawning /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch: No such file or directory

Comment: @Oelmounkad, using tar installation ? please follow https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/targz.html official link

Comment: @Oelmounkad, pl install in ubuntu home folder like /home/ubuntu and check `whoami` command it should return `ubuntu`

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja i did all this and it shows the same problem, this is strange.
error : imgur.com/a/gWDCTnm

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja actually i tried starting it with ./bin/elasticsearch but this new error came up : imgur.com/a/pTfPuP6  its jvm related

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja i resolved the last problem ! all works fine now, Thanks a lot for your time !

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja for the last one i just had to give elastic ownership to the user  :
chown "username" "elasticsearch-folder" .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213590/discussion-between-opster-elasticsearch-ninja-and-oelmounkad).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was resolved by using the tarball installation by following the official https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/targz.html installation instructions.

Please make sure the user which you are using to run the elasticsearch process has write access to the filesystem where the elasticsearch process is writing. Please see the comments in the question section for more info and error related to this.

Please use https://askubuntu.com/questions/6723/change-folder-permissions-and-ownership for instructions on how to assign the ownership in ubuntu.